# Перестало появляться окно ввода пароля

Tags: linux, cinnamon

Операционка Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon. При установке кое-какого софта, ругался на права доступа. Почитал гугл и сделал такую вещь:

```
sudo chown -R root.root /usr
```

После этой комманды слетело `sudo`. Его я восстановил, но от моих качелей осталось эхо. Если через GUI хочу посмотреть пользователей или установить или удалить что-нибудь, раньше появлялось окошко ввода пароля, сечас ничего. Та же песня, есил хочу папку открыть с рут правами, нажимаю правой Open as root и не появляется окошко. Может это как-то лечится?

Comment: Будет наука - не выполнять бездумно команды из интернета и тем более не менять права системных директориев. Что выдает ``whoami``?

Comment: @Эникейщик  выдаёт имя пользователя

Comment: А ``groups``? Рут есть в списке? А судо?

Comment: @Эникейщик `chernya2010 root sudo`

Comment: Попробуйте ``deluser chernya2010 root``, это удалит вас из группы root. Потом надо будет разлогиниться и снова зайти в систему.

Comment: @Эникейщик Через теминал по рут директориям бегает нормально, и редактирует. Проблема только, в том, что окошко для ввода пароля не появляется.

Comment: Т.к. пользователь в группе рут, то он и воспринимается как рут (мое предположение).

Comment: @Эникейщик не прокатило